# Como tomar latitud y longitd con boton android

Tags: android

Buenas tardes chicos, estoy implementando un proceso que debe tomar las coordenadas geográficas al hacer click a un botón, actualmente tengo este código para tomar las coordenadas, pero no me funciona :(

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.pedromendieta.ipal.MainActivity;
import com.example.pedromendieta.ipal.ValidarCumplimiento;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private ValidarCumplimiento padre;

    public ValidarCumplimiento getMainActivity() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setMainActivity(ValidarCumplimiento padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        this.padre.setLocation(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // Este mŽtodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
//        "GPS Desactivado";
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // Este mŽtodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
//        messageTextView.setText("GPS Activado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // Este mŽtodo se ejecuta cada vez que se detecta un cambio en el
        // status del proveedor de localizaci—n (GPS)
        // Los diferentes Status son:
        // OUT_OF_SERVICE -> Si el proveedor esta fuera de servicio
        // TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE -> Temp˜ralmente no disponible pero se
        // espera que este disponible en breve
        // AVAILABLE -> Disponible
    }
}
```

en la clase validar cumplimiento en el Oncreate tengo esto:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MyLocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocListener.setMainActivity(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
```

y por finalizar este es el metodo setLocation() al que se llama en la clase MyLocationListener en el evento onLocationChanged:

```
public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direcci—n de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                lat = loc.getLatitude() + "";
                lng = loc.getLongitude() + "";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ojala me puedan sacar del aprieto, muchas gracias

Comment: Y donde esta el botòn agrega la clase completa por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiar los parámetros que envías al método requestLocationUpdates(); así:

```
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000*60, 5, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
```

El primer parámetro es el proveedor que utilizarás en este caso el GPS

El segundo parámetro es el tiempo en que solicitaras las actualizaciones en mili segundos por lo que 1000*60 es igual a un minuto (Tu lo tienes en cero por lo tanto no estas solicitando actualizaciones)

El tercer parámetro es la distancia mínima entre actualizaciones en metros (Tu lo tienes en cero por lo tanto no estas solicitando actualizaciones).